# Redirection Failed in Thyemeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

> I am using thyemleaf in my application ,when I try to redirect from
> one page to another page by the help href tag, It is not able to
> redirect me to target page ,Throws Error 404 page not found.Her
> I am getting  Whitable Error page 404
> Here is my function for of register controller

```
@GetMapping("/register")
    fun register():String{
        return "redirect:/Register"
    }
```

> Register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>UserRegistration</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/nav :: navbar">

</div>
<section class="vh-100" style="background-color: #eee;">
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-11">
                <div class="card text-black" style="border-radius: 25px;">
                    <div class="card-body p-md-5">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-5 order-2 order-lg-1">

                                <p class="text-center h1 fw-bold mb-5 mx-1 mx-md-4 mt-4">Sign up</p>

                                <form class="mx-1 mx-md-4" th:action="" th:method="get">

                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                        <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                        <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                            <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" />
                                            <label class="form-label" for="fname">Your Name</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                        <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                        <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                            <input type="text" id="phNo" class="form-control" />
                                            <label class="form-label" for="phNo">your MobileNumber</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                        <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                        <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                            <input type="email" id="emId" class="form-control" />
                                            <label class="form-label" for="emId">Your Email</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                        <i class="fas fa-lock fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                        <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                            <input type="password" id="psw" class="form-control" />
                                            <label class="form-label" for="psw">Password</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                        <i class="fas fa-key fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                        <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                            <input type="password" id="repsw" class="form-control" />
                                            <label class="form-label" for="repsw">Repeat your password</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center mb-5">
                                        <input
                                                class="form-check-input me-2"
                                                type="checkbox"
                                                value=""
                                                id="form2Example3c"
                                        />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" th:for="form2Example3">
                                            I agree all statements in <a href="#!">Terms of service</a>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-4 mb-3 mb-lg-4">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</button>
                                    </div>

                                </form>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-7 d-flex align-items-center order-1 order-lg-2">

                                <img src="/static/images/register.webp" class="img-fluid" alt="Sample image">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

> nav.html

```
<div th:fragment="navbar">
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" th:href="@{/Register}">MenuBar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

> Here in my nav html file i provide the PageContext Redirection, But it
> is not able to redirect me to Register.html page while I click on
> MenuBar Button in my navbar I am using IntelIj Idea ultimate2021.1
> version as code editor and mac for os

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that need to be addressed in order to solve your problem.

1. In Spring MVC request mapping is case-sensitive, thus `/register` is not equal to `/Register`, hence the `404` error.
2. If you change the redirect to `redirect:/register` and your link to `th:href="@{/register}"` your `register()` function will create an endless redirection loop resulting in `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. If you want to return your `Register.html` template you should just `return "Register"` if your template resolver is configured to add `.html` prefix automatically or `return "Register.html"` if not.